# Substitute for Lookup() in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a bookkeeping sheet.

The aim is to create rules, that search imported fields from our bank statement, and if a match is found automatically fill the adjoining cells with the rules data.

example:

Data:

```
HEAD - Imported Field       - Payees (autofill) - Account (autofill)
ROW1 - payment to JASON U   - from rule below   - from rule below
ROW2 - 234322 MERCHANT FEES - from rule below   - from rule below
```

Rules:(separate sheet)

```
HEAD - Matched Term - Payee     - Account
ROW1 - JASON U      - Jason Ure - Drawings
ROW2 - MERCHANT     - CBA       - Fees
```

We have this working in Excel now, but need to get it working in Google Spreadsheets. 
Anyone know how to convert this? (see in skydrive/excel below)
[image: http://puu.sh/4DVsJ.png]

Answer (score 1):

At this time, the [LOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en) function is available in the [New Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3541068?hl=en).